# Link Tracking Breaks Large List Views in Modern

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, top-link-bar, links

All

I've done the requisite searching and couldn't quite find anything relevant for this.

Essentially, the link tracking that SharePoint uses appears to break the 'Views' functionality in a Modern experience. Here's an example link tracker:

```
?viewpath=%2Fsales%2Flists%2Fsale%20list%2FAllItems.aspx
```

Obviously that shouldn't break anything, and I don't think it usually *would*, because SPO adding that tracking to a link is business as usual.

However every single time I create a navigation link to the AllItems.aspx link, when left-clicked (middle and right are fine) it will add the link tracking, and the views break.

I've put in work around links elsewhere. My 'fix' is to use the site URL, since the list is already the homepage of the site. This is absolutely fine as a fix for the client, because their list is a million years old, and bigger than the sun. They only use the list, and no other site functionality on the site that it's stored on. This bypasses the tracking, and loads the views.

**So, I'm questioning myself on this.** Is this happening because of the list size/age (pre-modern) and interacting with the link tracking is simply just too much for SPO to handle?

**Or is there something else** that I've not considered here? I'm not ashamed to not know the answer here, but I'm hoping that I do, heh! Also, I'm not spitting on the client, this is how things go.

Best
Eliot

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my SharePoint Online environment with both

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/.../AllItems.aspx
```

and

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/.../AllItems.aspx?viewpath=%2FLists%2F...%2FAllItems.aspx
```

Everything seems to work just fine.

I agree with you that this link shouldn’t break anything, so I think you can pass the idea of “link tracking is too much for SPO to handle”.

What if you test in another site? Or is it possible for you to create a new list in the same site?

Comment: Hi, Chelsea, thanks for the response!

Sorry, editing, comments are not great here ;-) ...

I believe that the key isn't that the Link Tracking (aggregation?) is breaking things, more that nothing has *really* been done about the underlying problems of large lists. However, I don't think that approaches the incident easily enough.

The key here is the client's extremely large list, over 6000 items.

That's fine with modern views, but other lists are fine with the tracking, so I think it's a combination.

Answer (score 0):

View path generally gives a weird result when you move from classic to modern SPO site. We faced this during the migration. The home page was a classic SharePoint page and there were hyperlinks added on to the same, with one of them pointing to a list on the same site. After the migration the home page retained the classic look but when we clicked on the link to the list (datasheet view) it failed to show horizontal scrolls (when opened up on the same page), which was not the case when the link was opened up in a new page altogether (right click open in a new tab). If I remove everything after the viewpath in the URL and refreshed the page, I got the scrolls then. I later tried updating the hyperlinks on the classic home page so that it opens the link without the viewpath but it didnt help.
I had to later create the home page in the modern layout and add the hyperlinks there in order to get rid of that issue. I am sure this would be weird and please excuse me if I have limited knowledge on how it works, I am just sharing my experience.